# wwwroot folder not being loaded

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core

I'm developing a ASP.NET core application, and using the wwwroot/ folder to load my css, javascript, etc.

On my Visual Studio project I have the following structure:

[image: Vistual studio project tree view]

However when I look at the loaded sources in Chrome, the "font" folder never gets loaded:
[image: Chrome source structure]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you load your fonts within css?

Comment: Yes, like this: @font-face {
 font-family: entypo-fontello;
 src: url('font/entypo-fontello.eot'), url('font/entypo-fontello.woff');
}

Comment: Refresh the browser whilst the dev tools window is opened.

Comment: Please do not use .NET Core when you mean ASP.NET Core! These are two completely different things. .NET Core is a runtime which runs on multiple platforms (with limited API compared to .NET Framework), but ASP.NET Core is a webstack/framework for creating Web applications

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the problem.

The font files won't be loaded unless you have an element using the font, Despite having them referenced in the CSS file.

Comment: That did work for me as well. I was just about to investigate this behavior as well.

Comment: Optimization by browsers :) One less call.